# Weird loading/unloading of a comctl32.dll on app startup

Tags: .net, winforms

On program startup, in debugger trace, I can see this:

```
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll'
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll'
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll'
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll'
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll'
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll'
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll'
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll'
```

This is only a snippet.  It goes on for 100 lines at a time...

Can anyone explain why???

EDIT:

I am running x86 code under x64 Windows, and am getting also this in the trace window:

```
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x504b0000', No symbols loaded.
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x5720000', No symbols loaded.
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Unloaded 'ImageAtBase0x504b0000'

'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x54610000', No symbols loaded.
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x65c0000', No symbols loaded.
'VideoPhillPlayer.exe': Unloaded 'ImageAtBase0x54610000'
```

Comment: From the immediate upvotes, it seems that I'm not the only one with the problem?

Comment: I recall having seen it some time ago, and disregarded it because I was too busy. That's why I'm interested. As per a possible way to investigate the problem, maybe the [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and [Fusion logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tools can help you.

Comment: I don't know how.  For some reason, it load/unloads, and there is nothing in-between those events.  Ummm...

Comment: With Process Monitor you can check which processes are accessing comctl32.dll, and with Fusion logs you can check in which locations the CLR is seeking that dll. Altough the latter might not help so much since it seems to always find it in the same location. Check with Task Manager if there are any lingering instances of your .exe running

Comment: It is always same instance, and always is running only one.  I am talking about F5 from Visual Studio...

Comment: Right-click the Output window and untick "Module load messages".  Stops you from having to worry about code you didn't write and likely can't change.

Comment: Does your app eventually load without any problems? Or does it just do this indefinitely?

Comment: @HansPassant it seems reasonable, but app LOAD TIME is increased because of manic loading/unloading...  BTW, putting head in the sand seems perfectly good option from time to time, but I am really curious about this.

Comment: @CodyGray it does load eventually, but it takes it a rather long time

Comment: I had a similar (?) slow loading app once.  Turns out, I had setup loading symbols to a PDB over the internet in Tools --> Options --> Debugging/Symbols.  Not sure if that helps.  Maybe you can try excluding the comctl32.dll symbols from being loaded from those locations?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has some general information about ComCtl32.dll.  Long story short, this is nothing to worry about.  It's a DLL that contains UI components for Windows, and is therefore used all over the place by Windows applications: ComCtl is short for common controls.  You see it loading and unloading because various windows and other controls in your application are making use of its functions.

For those who would like a more thorough answer, you can run

```
dumpbin /exports C:\Windows\System32\ComCtl32.dll
```

to get a nice big batch of functions exported by the DLL.  For those who are both curious and lazy, here it is - you can see it just contains various utility functions for Windows controls:

```
Dump of file C:\Windows\System32\comctl32.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for COMCTL32.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    4CE779FD time date stamp Sat Nov 20 02:34:21 2010
        0.00 version
           2 ordinal base
         420 number of functions
         119 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

        401    0 0000912C AddMRUStringW
        400    1 00008F94 CreateMRUListW
          8    2 00009F9C CreateMappedBitmap
         12    3 0000CD80 CreatePropertySheetPage
         18    4 0000CD80 CreatePropertySheetPageA
         19    5 0000CD70 CreatePropertySheetPageW
         20    6 00014AC8 CreateStatusWindow
          6    7 00014AC8 CreateStatusWindowA
         21    8 00014A64 CreateStatusWindowW
          7    9 00016190 CreateToolbar
         22    A 00016028 CreateToolbarEx
         16    B 0001FC64 CreateUpDownControl
        331    C 00020C54 DPA_Clone
        328    D 00020B98 DPA_Create
        340    E 00020BA8 DPA_CreateEx
        337    F 00020FCC DPA_DeleteAllPtrs
        336   10 00020F0C DPA_DeletePtr
        329   11 00020C0C DPA_Destroy
        386   12 00021080 DPA_DestroyCallback
        385   13 00021014 DPA_EnumCallback
        332   14 00020CDC DPA_GetPtr
        333   15 00020D00 DPA_GetPtrIndex
        330   16 00020D40 DPA_Grow
        334   17 00020E80 DPA_InsertPtr
          9   18 00021258 DPA_LoadStream
         11   19 00021408 DPA_Merge
         10   1A 000210A4 DPA_SaveStream
        339   1B 00021810 DPA_Search
        335   1C 00020DFC DPA_SetPtr
        338   1D 000215D8 DPA_Sort
        320   1E 00020790 DSA_Create
        327   1F 00020B58 DSA_DeleteAllItems
        326   20 00020AB4 DSA_DeleteItem
        321   21 000207D8 DSA_Destroy
        388   22 00020898 DSA_DestroyCallback
        387   23 0002082C DSA_EnumCallback
        322   24 000208BC DSA_GetItem
        323   25 000208F8 DSA_GetItemPtr
        324   26 000209E8 DSA_InsertItem
        325   27 00020914 DSA_SetItem
        413   28 00022318 DefSubclassProc
         23   29 0000C378 DestroyPropertySheetPage
         24   2A 0007E480 DllGetVersion
         15   2B 000230F8 DrawInsert
         25   2C 00012EFC DrawStatusText
          5   2D 00012EFC DrawStatusTextA
         26   2E 00012ED0 DrawStatusTextW
        403   2F 000099B0 EnumMRUListW
         27   30 00025980 FlatSB_EnableScrollBar
         28   31 000255BC FlatSB_GetScrollInfo
         29   32 000252C8 FlatSB_GetScrollPos
         30   33 000254D8 FlatSB_GetScrollProp
         31   34 0002533C FlatSB_GetScrollPropPtr
         32   35 00025508 FlatSB_GetScrollRange
         33   36 000268C4 FlatSB_SetScrollInfo
         34   37 000266F0 FlatSB_SetScrollPos
         35   38 000269D0 FlatSB_SetScrollProp
         36   39 00026790 FlatSB_SetScrollRange
         37   3A 000256CC FlatSB_ShowScrollBar
        152   3B 0000906C FreeMRUList
          4   3C 000270D8 GetEffectiveClientRect
         38   3D 00027650 GetMUILanguage
         39   3E 000784B0 ImageList_Add
         40   3F 00078158 ImageList_AddIcon
         41   40 000786E8 ImageList_AddMasked
         42   41 00077C6C ImageList_BeginDrag
         43   42 00078A2C ImageList_Copy
         44   43 00077EB8 ImageList_Create
         45   44 000783C4 ImageList_Destroy
         46   45 00077CE0 ImageList_DragEnter
         47   46 00077D58 ImageList_DragLeave
         48   47 00077D20 ImageList_DragMove
         49   48 00077D8C ImageList_DragShowNolock
         50   49 00078840 ImageList_Draw
         51   4A 00078748 ImageList_DrawEx
         52   4B 00078914 ImageList_DrawIndirect
         53   4C 0007820C ImageList_Duplicate
         54   4D 00077C18 ImageList_EndDrag
         55   4E 000785C4 ImageList_GetBkColor
         56   4F 00077BD0 ImageList_GetDragImage
         57   50 00078D60 ImageList_GetFlags
         58   51 000789CC ImageList_GetIcon
         59   52 00078AA0 ImageList_GetIconSize
         60   53 0007840C ImageList_GetImageCount
         61   54 00078B74 ImageList_GetImageInfo
         62   55 0007835C ImageList_GetImageRect
         63   56 00077F74 ImageList_LoadImage
         64   57 00077F74 ImageList_LoadImageA
         65   58 00078020 ImageList_LoadImageW
         66   59 00078BD8 ImageList_Merge
         67   5A 000782C8 ImageList_Read
         68   5B 00078978 ImageList_Remove
         69   5C 00078674 ImageList_Replace
         70   5D 00078510 ImageList_ReplaceIcon
         75   5E 00078570 ImageList_SetBkColor
         76   5F 00077B4C ImageList_SetDragCursorImage
         77   60 00079FF8 ImageList_SetFilter
         78   61 00078C98 ImageList_SetFlags
         79   62 00078B0C ImageList_SetIconSize
         80   63 00078458 ImageList_SetImageCount
         81   64 00078610 ImageList_SetOverlayImage
         82   65 00078260 ImageList_Write
         17   66 0002751C InitCommonControls
         83   67 00027528 InitCommonControlsEx
         84   68 00027618 InitMUILanguage
         85   69 000233F4 InitializeFlatSB
         14   6A 00022FA0 LBItemFromPt
         13   6B 00022F0C MakeDragList
          2   6C 00026DA8 MenuHelp
         86   6D 00012820 PropertySheet
         87   6E 00012820 PropertySheetA
         88   6F 00012810 PropertySheetW
         89   70 00027660 RegisterClassNameW
        412   71 00022244 RemoveWindowSubclass
        410   72 00022138 SetWindowSubclass
          3   73 00026FD0 ShowHideMenuCtl
        236   74 00021B38 Str_SetPtrW
         90   75 00023260 UninitializeFlatSB
         91   76 0002BF50 _TrackMouseEvent
         71      00009BF0 [NONAME]
         72      00009C08 [NONAME]
         73      00009C38 [NONAME]
         74      00009C58 [NONAME]
        151      00009058 [NONAME]
        153      000093B0 [NONAME]
        154      00009A74 [NONAME]
        155      00009948 [NONAME]
        156      000093FC [NONAME]
        157      00008FA8 [NONAME]
        163      0000CABC [NONAME]
        164      00012610 [NONAME]
        167      000094E8 [NONAME]
        169      0000971C [NONAME]
        233      000219BC [NONAME]
        234      00021BBC [NONAME]
        235      00021918 [NONAME]
        341      00028BD4 [NONAME]
        342      00027A44 [NONAME]
        350               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#78)
        351               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#79)
        352               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#80)
        353               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#81)
        354               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#82)
        355               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#83)
        356               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#84)
        357               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#85)
        358               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#86)
        359               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#87)
        360               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#88)
        361               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#89)
        362               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#90)
        363               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#91)
        364               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#92)
        365               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#93)
        366               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#94)
        367               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#95)
        368               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#96)
        369               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#97)
        372               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#98)
        373               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#99)
        374               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#100)
        375               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#101)
        376               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#102)
        377               [NONAME] (forwarded to SHUNIMPL.#103)
        382      0000AF70 [NONAME]
        383      000228E0 [NONAME]
        384      0002B5C0 [NONAME]
        389      00079FF8 [NONAME]
        390      00078CEC [NONAME]
        402      0000980C [NONAME]
        404      00008B00 [NONAME]
        411      00022098 [NONAME]
        414      000276E8 [NONAME]
        415      000719C0 [NONAME]
        416      00071998 [NONAME]
        417      00071904 [NONAME]
        418      000718C0 [NONAME]
        419      000718D0 [NONAME]
        420      000718D0 [NONAME]
        421      00071968 [NONAME]

  Summary

        4000 .data
        5000 .pdata
        1000 .reloc
        7000 .rsrc
       8E000 .text
```

Comment: This just explains what ComCtl32.dll *is*, it doesn't explain why the assembly needs to be loaded and unloaded hundreds of times.

Comment: Sure it does.  It's used by Windows controls for miscellaneous purposes.  For example, look up the documentation for CreateToolbarEx.  If the OP's application has a toolbar, that function is probably getting called.  I can't get specific, because the functions being called aren't listed, but the point is that this DLL is going to be used by pretty much any Windows program out there.

Comment: So each time that a function exported by this DLL is called, the entire module is loaded and unloaded? Is that what you're saying? That seems wasteful. The debugger trace output isn't saying that a function call was made, it's saying that the module was loaded (and then unloaded).

Comment: This is indeed not very helpful. Comtl32.dll implements the common controls since Windows 95, but the question remains why the loader loads a DLL first and then unloads it. If it uses an export it can't even be unloaded. Also this behavior is applied to other DLLs as well.